# Creating a list of all possible nested sequences from another list

Tags: python

```
 List1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'd like to produce the following list2 containing four-element nested sequences from list1.

```
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
    [0, 1, 2, 4]
    [0, 1, 2, 5]
    [0, 1, 3, 4]
    [0, 1, 3, 5]
    [0, 1, 4, 5]
    [0, 2, 3, 4]
    [0, 2, 3, 5]
    [0, 2, 4, 5]
    [0, 3, 4, 5]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 5]
    [1, 2, 4, 5]
    [1, 3, 4, 5]
    [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The eventual problem will use list1 with more elements and list2 with more than four-element nested sequences.  However, I believe the logic is the same and hope the example is clear.

I'm basically looking for all “x-element” progressive nested sequences possible from a given list1.

I've written a loop to produce list2 with three-element nested sequences.  Unfortunately, my solution is ugly and the more elements in my nested sequences, the uglier it gets.  My guess/hope is this is a known math problem with a simple Python solution.  My research leads me to believe it's a recursion problem, but I'm having a difficult time translating it into code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Basically, what you are looking for is:

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)
```

Comment: `[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)]` to get a list of lists.

Comment: or `map(list, itertools.combinations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))`

Comment: Thank you.  Itertools.combinations is a wonderful solution.  I was unaware of the module and it appears I'll be able to use it in other scripts.  I'd spent several hours cobbling together a clunky solution that your answer accomplished in minutes.

Comment: if you [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) please [label it appropriately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!